# Calling an applet from existing form submit button in a JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, applet

I have an applet added as a jar in my spring-mvc application.
The applet is used to digitally sign a document before it is submitted using the form submit button.
I have made a call to applet code from my JSP:

```
<object
    codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5-windows-i586.cab#Version=5,0,0,5"
    width="130" height="25" name="SmartCardSignerApplet">
    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5">
    <param name="code" value="com.smartcard.encryption.SmartCardSignerApplet">
    <param name="archive" value="SmartCardSignerApplet.jar">
    <param name="codebase" value="/Application/applet">
    <param name="mayscript" value="true">
    <param name="scriptable" value="true">
    <param name="fileNameField" value="hashCode">
    <param name="formNameField" value="approvalForm">
    <param name="certificationChainField" value="certChain">
    <param name="signatureField" value="encryptedtext">
    <param name="signButtonCaption" value="Encrypt Data">

    <comment>
        <embed
            type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5"
            pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/index.html#download"
            code="com.smartcard.encryption.SmartCardSignerApplet"
            archive="/Application/applet/SmartCardSignerApplet.jar"
            width="130"
            height="25"
            mayscript="true"
            scriptable="true"
            scriptable="true"
            fileNameField="hashCode"
            formNameField="approvalForm"
            certificationChainField="certChain"
            signatureField="encryptedtext"
            signButtonCaption="Encrypt Data">
        </embed>
        <noembed>
            Smart card signing applet can not be started because
            Java Plugin 1.5 or newer is not installed.
        </noembed>
    </comment>
</object>
```

This embeds a button 'Encrypt Data' on the JSP page and click of this button calls the applet code.
Also I have a submit button in my form:

```
 <form:form id = form> 
   ........................
 ........................ 
 <input type="submit" value="Approve" id="approveBttn" >
 </form:form>
```

These two buttons are working fine for their specific purposes. 
My requirement is to use a single button for applet call and form submit(after successful applet processing).
Can I add the applet call to existing form submit button. Or is it possible to submit my form using the embedded button used for applet call.
I am relatively new to applets so please let me know if I have missed to add any details.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `javascript` functions through the applet java code using the `netscape.javascript.JSObject` object in your main applet class. So the thing is that you can create a `javascript` function which works as a callback function when applet finish its operations, in this `callback` function you can perform your submit operation to achieve your goal.

This could be something like:

In your JS:

```
// this callback function will be called from applet
function callbackFn(){
  document.getElementById('yourFormId').submit();
}
```

In your applet:

```
public class YourApplet extends JApplet {
...
  public void yourMethod() {
     // perform your operations
     ...
     // when it's finished call javascript function
     Object[] params = ...; // params are passed to javascript function, could be null
     JSObject.getWindow(this).call("callbackFn", params);
  }

}
```

So when the user clicks on applet button, the operations is performed and then applet calls javascript callback function which submits your form.

NOTE: To use `netscape.javascript.JSObject` in your source code you have to add `JRE_HOME/lib/plugin.jar` in your build path.

Hope this helps,